# Receiving RabbitMQ message from one channel, set the messageId in the transformer and send it to other channel using Spring Integration

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-integration

I'm new to RabbitMQ and Spring Integration.

I have a use case to consume JSON message from a channel, convert it to an object. One of the field that I need to set in the object is the message Id(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag()) of the message that we receive from rabbitMQ which we need for ack handling after all the business logic.

How to do it using spring integration?
Here is my xml configuration.

```
       <bean id="devRabbitmqConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="#{props[rabbitmq_inputjms_url]}" />
            <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
      </bean>   

     <bean id="devJMSCachingConnectionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
            <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="devRabbitmqConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="10" />
            <property name="cacheProducers" value="false" />
      </bean>

      <int-jms:channel id="devJMSChannel" acknowledge="transacted"
            connection-factory="devJMSCachingConnectionFactory" message-driven="false"
            queue-name="devJMSChannel">

      </int-jms:channel> 
      <bean id="redeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
        <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="5000" />
        <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
      </bean>

    <int:transformer id="devObjectTransformer" input-channel="devJMSChannel"  ref="devService" method="readEventFromRabbitMQ"
                output-channel="devPacketChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10" task-executor="devObjectTransformerExecutor" />
    </int:transformer>
```

The transformer method "readEventFromRabbitMQ" gets the message String from msg.getPayload() converts it into object and sends it to the output channel. But not sure how to get the message Id in the transformer class. Can somebody help me with this?

```
public List<DevEventRecord> readEventFromRabbitMQ(Message<EventsDetail> msg){
         DevEventRecord[] eventRecords=null;
         EventsDetail expEvent = null;
         long receivedTime =System.currentTimeMillis();
         int packetId = -1;
         try{
             monitorBean.incrementDeviceExceptionPacketCount();
             expEvent = msg.getPayload();
             LogUtil.debug("readExceptionEvent :: consumed JMS Q "+expEvent);
             eventRecords = dispatchPacket(expEvent);
         }
         catch(ProcessingException pe){
             notifyAck(expEvent.getUniqueId(),,,,);
         }
         catch(Exception ex){
             notifyAck(expEvent.getUniqueId(),,,,);
             LogUtil.error("Exception occured while reading object in readEvent , "+ex.toString());
         }
         return getEventRecordList(eventRecords);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `deliveryTag` is presented as message header after an `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` under the key `AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG`.

I don't understand why you mix `AMQP` and `JMS`, but anyway those channel implementations don't populate headers from received message. It is out of their responcibity.

Please, use `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` and here is a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-amqp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/amqp/inbound/ManualAckTests.java) how to `ack` message manually using `deliveryTag` header.

Comment: Bear in mind it is generally unnecessary to manually ack messages with Spring AMQP - by default, the container will ack the message when the consumer thread returns normally after processing the message. The container will reject (and by default requeue) the message if the flow throws an exception. The delivery tag is only available as a header when using `MANUAL` acks.